# How to connect mongoDB to angular2 app?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, angular

I have `angular2 & mongoDB` configured.
So far I am able to read json files using http service but I want to develop a complete application which will have database connectivity too.

So i would like to know how can I configure my angular2 app so that it can interact with the database.

Any inputs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Bhushan, I believe till now you have implemented  mongo and angular2. I have a small question, by reading the answers below I understood, to implement mongo with angular to I have to run another server, like nodejs or expressjs for connection with mongo/creating a rest service. and the lite server of angular 2 cant handle the connection.  Is this correct understanding?

Comment: @Arijit Lite server  will eventually run the front end. node servers like express,loopback are good options to go with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should utilise a framework such as ExpressJS to handle the interaction with the database which returns JSON data in the same way as you are currently doing with a static file.

There are quite a few tutorials around which explain how to do this such as http://adrianmejia.com/blog/2014/10/01/creating-a-restful-api-tutorial-with-nodejs-and-mongodb/

The other option you have is to use a framework to do much of the heavy lifting around building the API. [Loopback](https://loopback.io/) is a good start for such a task as they have a generator which can generate client side code to interact with your API making the implementation much easier than building everything yourself. I haven't used it in a while so I'm not sure if they have ng2 as a client side generator yet, but it might be a good place to start.

Comment: But Loopback is not fully open source, I found some license terms here [link](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/SL/Managing+your+licenses) ,  can you provide some information on it..?

Comment: Thats true @RajBhatia and many commonly used open source projects are the same as far as having licensed products/services. There are parts of the strongloop ecosystem which are licensed such as `slc arc` but the basic loopback framework doesn't require `slc` to operate and connect to databases such as mongo. Most of the licensed parts of strongloop are related to enterprise focused tech such as SQL server and Oracle connectors and management systems for your loopback api's etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a server side framework like hapijs, expressjs etc where you have to make a connection by mentioning your database url like

`mongodb://username:password@ds012367.mlab.com:12367/dbName

which then connects your app to database.