# How can I connect Angularjs 2 with mogodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, client, database

I am trying to find how to make connectivity of Angularjs 2 with mongodb.
I have one application that accepts the some data from the user and save into the database.
Database I use right now in mysql,but mysql is very slow.So I need replacement with mongodb.

Comment: You need middleware like `express.js` for connectivity to mongodb with packages like `mongoose` etc

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137664/how-to-connect-mongodb-to-angular2-app